# can not load en_core_web_sm

Tags: python, spacy

I have problems with spacy
I downloaded using this command in Anaconda prompt (anaconda3)

```
 python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

After the download,  it notified:

```
Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

I ran these codes in Spyder these lines:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

This error popped up

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I am confused because I have received this notification in Anaconda prompt: You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') but still encountered error in Spyder

How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that you're using the same python interpreter for the download and for the loading?

Comment: how to check that? sorry I'm new to Python

Comment: Oh I figured it out. I restarted the Anaconda and it works

Comment: Can you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` in the prompt that you used to download spacy and add the same lines in your IDE and run those?

Comment: use *python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm*